# My VScode doesnt allow me to leave a spacing or a line. How do i fix this?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I have tried disabling my extensions or deleting the settings.json but nothing has worked. Every time I leave a line or spacing they always show this file is 'unsaved' and as an error then corrects it like some autocorrect feature but I can't turn it off. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> on Windows, or <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> on MacOS to open the **Settings** panel.
2. Type `on save` in the search field.
3. Disable `Format on save`.
4. Just close the settings, they are live settings, no need to save changes made.

[image: Where to disable format on save]